# Objective C: Calling instance method from class method

Tags: objective-c

this is the problem:

**myObject.h**

```
@interface myObject
- (void) Init;
- (void) doStuffs;
- (void) Final;
+ (NSData*) staticMethod: (NSString*) filePath
@end
```

**myObject.m**

```
@implementation myObject

- (void) Init {
...
}

- (void) doStuffs {
...
}

- (void) Final {
...
}

+ (NSData*) staticMethod: (NSString*) filePath {
    myObject *objInstance;

    [objInstance Init];
    [objInstance doStuffs];
    [objInstance Final];
}
@end
```

When calling **Init**, **doStuffs** and **Final** on the static method, the instance methods are not called; any idea?

For short: I need to call instance method from a static method of the same class...

Thank you for helping.

Comment: alloc/init of `objInstance` isn't done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't created an instance of `myObject`. So, assuming ARC, you're calling on `nil`. Calling on `nil` doesn't do anything.

So:

```
myObject *objInstance = [[myObject alloc] init];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't initialize objInstance, it'll be nil and those calls won't do anything. Allocate and initialize objInstance first. You can also check objInstance for nil before calling those methods and you'll see it is nil.

This is one of the trickier things about Objective-C. Java would throw a NullPointerException if you tried something like this. Objective-C silently keeps chugging along!